# Startup script to start a detached screen and run a bash script inside

Tags: bash, ubuntu, npm

I have an issue with a startup script I've written and can't for the life of me figure out what's wrong. In essence, I want to start a detached screen, pass a daemon start command into the screen, then change directory and run "npm start" at the directory I've changed to.

Preferably, I'd like to install the screen script as a service, but I've had no success. Screens won't start at all. I've `screen -list` and even `sudo screen -list` while the service was installed. I've tried `Type=forking` `Type=oneshot` and still nothing.

Crontab is the only thing that has somewhat so far.

I've gotten the screen to stay open, however when I reattach to the screen I get the error:
/path/to/script.sh : 6: /path/to/script: npm: not found.

I used nvm to install node and npm. I tried linking to /usr/bin or /usr/local/bin with no success. Either errors with too many links, or node not found, even though its been linked.

For the scripts I have, the main script which starts the screens is

```
#!/bin/sh
SCRIPT_DIR=/path/to/script/folder/in/user/directory

screen -dmS nameofscreen bash -c $SCRIPT_DIR/script_to_run.sh
```

and the script that is supposed to be run is as follows:

```
#!/bin/sh
USR_BIN=/usr/local/bin

$USR_BIN/daemon_to_start -arg1 -arg2 &&
sleep 2
cd /path/to/npm/app/folder && npm start
sleep 3
exec $SHELL
```

Once again, with these scripts, the screen starts and stays open, however npm not found error is thrown. Also, if I use the absolute directory for npm, node not found becomes the new error. I've spent three days on this and never wrote a script. I'm starting to lose my mind.

PLEASE HELP!

EDIT: With the help of lojza and adding the node binary to my PATH, It somewhat works! Now when the startup script runs, only one screen is started. The script is supposed to start 4 screens. I've tried appending `&` and even `&&` to the end with no luck. I will continue searching.

Answer (score 0):

Call npm with full path:

```
/path/to/npm/app/folder/npm start
/usr/local/bin/npm start #in my case
```

or

```
cd /path/to/npm/app/folder && ./npm start
```

Comment: Thanks lojza! Calling npm with it's full path works! I did have to add the location of the node binary to my path as well, since when I would call npm's full path, I would get an error, `node, file or directory not found` .